# Load a page without opening windows

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I have tried to set cookies in multiples domain that i own (for a better user experience, they will be so directly logged in on my different domains)
The cookies is secured, i know we can edit it so it's a 64 random letters key for every users.
I've tried to load cookies with this https://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains/ method but apparently it didn't work because i so by inspect that google chrome (my browser) had block the request considering that as hacking.
So for now it's a button that allows the cookie to load by windows openning in javascript but the user has to close every single window when cookie are load (long and boring)

Is there any way to make my operation simple ?

Thanks for your help,
Your sincerely,
MySve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.close()` to close the current window. But opening a window for every domain isnt a good solution, and cross origin cookies arent great either.

I'd recommend doing it like this:

- Lets say that the user is on webpage 1, and logged in on webpage 4.
- Your button should redirect you to website 2.
- Website 2 should check if the user is logged in. The user is not logged in, so it redirect you to website 3.
- The user is not logged in on website 3 either, so it redirects you to website 4.
- The user is logged in on website 4, so it redirects you back to page 1.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Perfect, I'm going to work on that, thanks for your help :D !